# 'use strict' is not working on some special cases. Can anyone clarify

Tags: javascript

I am trying to figure out why "use strict" is not working as per my expectation. Look at this working example.

```js
"use strict"

x='Justin';
console.log(x)
```

As expected this produce error saying x is not defined. But check this next example

```js
"use strict"

name='Justin';
console.log(name)
```

It outputs "Justin" without any error. Why is it happening what is so special about the variable "name"?

Comment: its probably referencing `window.name` which is already declared.

Comment: Yes that was the issue. Very interesting and informative too.

Comment: `event` is another global that might make you trip too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run it in a browser, `name` refers to `name` property of the global object, which is `Window`. So it refers to [Window.name](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/API/Window/name).